# clang - getting body of the function

Tags: c++, clang

I'm trying to get the entire code of the function body.

I have the following code

```
    bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *f) {
      Stmt *FuncBody = f->getBody();
      stringstream SSAfter;
      SSAfter << f->getBody();
      SourceLocation ST = f->getSourceRange().getBegin();
      ST = FuncBody->getLocEnd().getLocWithOffset(1);
      TheRewriter.InsertText(ST, SSAfter.str(), true, true);
   }
```

I have the following code example

```
int multiplyOrSum (int a, int b, bool t)
{
    int c=0;
    if (a<=0){
        return 0;
    }
    if (t){
        c= a*b;
    }
    else {
        c = a+b;
    }
    __asm
    {
        jz  _P01
        jnz _P01
    //  _emit 0e9h
    _P01:
    }

    return (c + multiplyOrSum(a-1, b, t)+ loopOne (-1));
}
```

After parsing with the code that i provided. The outcome is

```
int multiplyOrSum (int a, int b, bool t)

{
    int c=0;
    if (a<=0){
        return 0;
    }
    if (t){
        c= a*b;
    }
    else {
        c = a+b;
    }
    __asm
    {
        jz  _P01
        jnz _P01
    //  _emit 0e9h
    _P01:
    }
    return (c + multiplyOrSum(a-1, b, t)+ loopOne (-1));
}
02053B28
```

What i want to achieve is

```
int multiplyOrSum (int a, int b, bool t)

    {
        int c=0;
        if (a<=0){
            return 0;
        }
        if (t){
            c= a*b;
        }
        else {
            c = a+b;
        }
        __asm
        {
            jz  _P01
            jnz _P01
        //  _emit 0e9h
        _P01:
        }
        return (c + multiplyOrSum(a-1, b, t)+ loopOne (-1));
    }

    {
        int c=0;
        if (a<=0){
            return 0;
        }
        if (t){
            c= a*b;
        }
        else {
            c = a+b;
        }
        __asm
        {
            jz  _P01
            jnz _P01
        //  _emit 0e9h
        _P01:
        }
        return (c + multiplyOrSum(a-1, b, t)+ loopOne (-1));
    }
```

Please advice. Thanks a lot

EDIT : Basically what i want to do is to duplicate the function body.

EDIT 2 :

I have tried the following code with some editing to my original

```
bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *f) {
      Stmt *FuncBody = f->getBody();
      stringstream SSAfter;
      SSAfter << f->getBody();
      LangOptions LangOpts;
      LangOpts.CPlusPlus = true;
      PrintingPolicy Policy(LangOpts);
      std::string s;
      llvm::raw_string_ostream as(s);
      FuncBody->printPretty(as, 0, Policy);
      SSAfter << as.str() << "\n";
      SourceLocation ST = f->getSourceRange().getBegin();
      ST = FuncBody->getLocEnd().getLocWithOffset(1);
      TheRewriter.InsertText(ST, SSAfter.str(), true, true);
   }
```

My output now is

```
int multiplyOrSum (int a, int b, bool t)
{
    int c=0;
    if (a<=0){
        return 0;
    }
    if (t){
        c= a*b;
    }
    else {
        c = a+b;
    }
    __asm
    {
        jz  _P01
        jnz _P01
    //  _emit 0e9h
    _P01:
    }
    return (c + multiplyOrSum(a-1, b, t)+ loopOne (-1));
}
{
    int c = 0;
    if (a <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

How am i going to get the entire body of the function? I have now gotten the first part. But what about the rest?

Comment: You want to duplicate the method body?

Comment: Why are you still using that ostringstream in the second example? Simplify that. The code looks like it should work, though - the behavior you're seeing is very strange.

Comment: @SebastianRedl It seems like the more logical thing to do to pass it through a ostream followed by printing pretty the stream. The behavior that i'm seeing is making me stuck as i require this to work before i can proceed to do other things that is required of me. Thats a reason why i'm looking for some advice from people here at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
string getExprAsString(Expr *expression)
{
    // Might return until the beginning of the last token though
    SourceRange exprRange = expression->getSourceRange();
    string exprString;

    int rangeSize = TheRewriter.getRangeSize(exprRange);
    if (rangeSize == -1) {
        return "";
    }

    SourceLocation startLoc = exprRange.getBegin();
    const char *strStart = TheSourceMgr.getCharacterData(startLoc);

    exprString.assign(strStart, rangeSize);

    return exprString;      
}

bool VisitFunctionDecl(FunctionDecl *f) {
    string funcBody = getExprAsString(f->getBody());

    SourceLocation ST = f->getBody()->getSourceRange().getBegin();
    ST = f->getBody()->getLocEnd().getLocWithOffset(1);

    // not sure if it contains the { } so added extra, just in case
    TheRewriter.InsertText(ST, "\n{\n" + funcBody + "\n}\n" , true, true);
}
```